# Comparing two survey items with a third variable

Tags: logistic, categorical-data, survey, binary-data

I want to compare the results of two items by age category and do not really know what test to use. I tried a [Cochran–Mantel–Haenzel–test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cochran%E2%80%93Mantel%E2%80%93Haenszel_statistics) at first, but I don't think it is testing what I really want to know.

We have two items (both dichotomous yes/no). We are interested in the proportion who said yes to item 2 if they said yes to item 1 and if this differs by age category.

Anyone have any ideas? I thought about doing a logistic regression with the "events" as those who chose item 2 and the "trials" as the number who chose item 1, with the age category as the dependent variable. Does that make sense?

Comment: Please tell us what you mean by a "CMH."

Comment: Cochran Mantel Haenzel test.

Comment: Are you *only* interested in whether the proportion of people who chose item 2, given that they chose item 1, differs by age category? What if this conditional proportion is constant by age category, but the proportion who chose item 1 differs by age, would you want to know that?  What if the proportion who chose item 2 given that they *didn't* choose item 1 differs by age, would you care about that?

Comment: I am interested in those who chose"yes" for item 1 and 2. I am not really interested in the other cells of the table, although if I get information about that, as long as I can answer my main question, I would be okay with that, too.

Comment: The main issue I'm having I suppose is just that some tests just tell you that there is no association (overall), not for a particular cell like I am interested in.

Answer (score 1):

Edited after clarification

Your logistic regression looks just fine. Maybe easier to sell, but similar, would be to use a chi squared test of independence between age and item 2 for people with positive item 1. An alternative to this test would be a trend test (e.g. test for non-zero Spearman rank correlation) that would consider the ordinal nature of age categories (also only for persons with positive answer to item 1).

Comment: What do you mean, simple stratification? I already know the proportions, I just want to know if they are significantly different between age groups.